# How to compare two HashMap in Java

Tags: java, hashmap

I need to compare two HashMap using Java.
I tried with equals() method, but that isn't working.
I think, maybe, that's why in HashMap equals() method uses object references to compare, and not object values.
Example:

```
/*FIRST HASHMAP*/
Posto p1 = new Posto("005","Cat1");
Posto p2 = new Posto("001", "Cat2");
Posto p3 = new Posto("009", "Cat2");
Posto p4 = new Posto("005","Cat3");

Map<String, Posto> posti = new HashMap<String, Posto>();

posti.put(p1.getCode(), p1);
posti.put(p2.getCode(), p2);
posti.put(p3.getCode(), p3);
posti.put(p4.getCode(), p4);

/*SECOND HASHMAP*/  
Posto p5 = new Posto("005","Cat1");
Posto p6 = new Posto("001", "Cat2");
Posto p7 = new Posto("009", "Cat2");
Posto p8 = new Posto("005","Cat3");

Map<String, Posto> pos = new HashMap<String, Posto>();

pos.put(p1.getCode(), p5);
pos.put(p2.getCode(), p6);
pos.put(p3.getCode(), p7);
pos.put(p4.getCode(), p8);

/*COMPARE*/
System.out.println(posti.equals(pos)); //THIS RETURNS FALSE (SHOULD BE TRUE)
```

Comment: override `equals` and `hashcode` in `Posto` otherwise show the `equals` and `hashcode` implementations if already implemented.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, you are not right by saying the `equals` method of the `HashMap` compares by references and not values. The `equals` method is inherited from the `AbstractMap`, which defines the equals method as following:

> This implementation first checks if the specified object is this map;
>   if so it returns true. Then, it checks if the specified object is a
>   map whose size is identical to the size of this map; if not, it
>   returns false. If so, it iterates over this map's entrySet collection,
>   and checks that the specified map contains each mapping that this map
>   contains. If the specified map fails to contain such a mapping, false
>   is returned. If the iteration completes, true is returned.

Source: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.html#equals(java.lang.Object)

As the comments suggest, make sure that the `hashCode` and `equals` methods of your class are correct.